# How to correctly ignore xml element in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm processing some XML file via XSLT transformation. However, in some files, there are elements which are not defined into my XSLT which I would like to ignore.

Here the XML structure:

```xml
<objects ....>
<do> [....] </do>
<ao> [....]. </ao>
</objects>
```

The element I need to skip it's the `<do>`

Here the header of the xslt file I wrote

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:pr="https://schema.easydb.de/EASYDB/1.0/objects/" exclude-result-prefixes="pr">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="pr:objects/pr:ao">
        <entry>
          ...
```

As resulting file I'm having

```
<root>
  0
                0         
                    141659
                    0
                    do
  <entry> Correct data </entry>
</root>
```

Whit all the values also from the `<do>` element.

I have then modified my code according to the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282742/xslt-exclude-an-element-but-keep-its-sub-elements)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:pr="https://schema.easydb.de/EASYDB/1.0/objects/" exclude-result-prefixes="pr">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="objects/ao">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

It partially work since as result I'm still having all the elements also from `<do>`

```xml
<root>
<do>
alement from do
</do>
  <entry xmlns=""> correct element </entry>
<root>
```

What I would like to have at the end

```
<root>
<entry> Correct data </entry>
</root>
```

What I have to modify on my code to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<xsl:template match="pr:do"/>` to block processing and copying these `do` elements.